# How do I stop/configure Neovis Physics

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am using NeoVis from JavaScript to render my Neo4j graph, and I want to be able disable and/or configure the physics of the render. Ideally I would like to be able to keep the render from moving beyond how I drag the nodes/edges. How do I do this?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can call stabilize on the neovis object assuming it was called `viz` it can be done with the following:

```js
viz.stabilize()
```